# ¿Que metodo de petición HTTP debería usar?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, http

Estoy creando un inicio de sesión, tengo el siguiente formulario

[image: Imagen de formulario con inputs y botones]

Al botón de Iniciar sesión se me ocurrió asignarle una función la cual tome los datos y haga una petición a la base de datos que debería retornar ya sea de alguna forma si esa cuenta de correo existe y es la contraseña correcta y ya de ahí a futuro implemento más cosas

```
let data = {
  email: email,
  password: password,
};

fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/Client/login", {
  method: "?????",
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => alert(error));
```

El problema es que no se que método debería asignarle tanto al fetch como en el backend

```
 @???Mapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> logging(@RequestBody Client client) {
        if (servicios.logging(client)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El método que deberías usar es POST

Comment: No entiendo porque esta respuesta tiene voto negativo, pero debería ser la respuesta correcta. Las peticiones GET van con los datos enviados dentro de la misma URL y además pueden ser cacheadas por cualquier servidor intermedio y normalmente tambien son visibles en los historiales de busqueda... nadie quisiera tener su usuario y su password visible para cualquier persona... sería demasiado inseguro mandarlo por GET. La respuesta correcta es POST!

Comment: Procura explicar el _por qué_ de usar POST (aunque realmente tu respuesta es corta y concisa). _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné usando el método GET, realmente lo que hay que hacer es cambiar la forma de mandar la información

```
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/Client/login/${email}/${password}`, {
          method: "GET",
          // body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 403) {
              console.log("La respuesta fue 403");
            }
            if (response.status == 200) {
              console.log("La respuesta fue 200");
            }
          })
          .catch((error) =>
            alert("El problema obtenido fue: " + error);
```

ya por la parte del backend recibo ambas variables

```
 @GetMapping("/login/{email}/{password}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> logging(
            @PathVariable("email") String email,
            @PathVariable("password") String password) {

        Client client = new Client(email, password);

        if (!servicios.canlogging(client)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

y las identifico con la anotación @PathVariable, ya con esas variables construyo el objeto y sigo con la lógica que necesito, y de acuerdo que si cumple o no, retorno el ResponseEntity

Comment: Pues tal como comentan en la otra respuesta, el método adecuado debería ser POST. La posibilidad de ver la contraseña en la URL como parte de la misma no es tan confiable. Saludos